# CRM Retrieve entity - Error: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity' to type 'CRMEntities.List'

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, early-binding

I generated entities from CRM like this:

```
CrmSvcUtil.exe /url:http://<servername>/<organizationname>/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc
    /out:<outputfilename>.cs /username:<username> /password:<password> /domain:<domainname>
    /namespace:CRMEntities /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext
```

For **serviceContextName** I set **XrmServiceContext**. 
I want to retrieve some entity from CRM using next code:

```
var context = new XrmServiceContext(myorgserv);
var marketingList = context.ListSet.Where(item => item.Id == new Guid("SOME GUID"));
```

And I'm getting error:

```
Message "Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity' to type 'CRMEntities.List'."
```

After 'add to watch' I saw that every set of entities in context have the same message.
What have I missed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Problem solved. After initializing **OrganizationServiceProxy**, I have to call 
**EnableProxyTypes** method.

```
OrganizationServiceProxy orgserv;
ClientCredentials clientCreds = new ClientCredentials();

    clientCreds.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = username;
    clientCreds.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = password;
    clientCreds.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = domain;
    IServiceConfiguration<IOrganizationService> orgConfigInfo = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration<IOrganizationService>(orgServiceUri);

    orgserv = new OrganizationServiceProxy(orgConfigInfo, clientCreds);
    orgserv.EnableProxyTypes();
```

Key thing is: **orgserv.EnableProxyTypes();**

Comment: Thank you!  Was banging my head against the wall, works perfectly!